# How to create a new col in the dataframe if a symbol exists in the first col

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame with some text read in from a txt file the column names are `FEATURE` and `SENTENCE`. Within the `FEATURE` col there is some text that has a `+` or a `-` symbol somewhere in the txt.

How can I create a new col called `RESULTS` and:

- if `+` exists in the `FEATURE` row then the new col will have a `positive`
- and if `-` exists the new `RESULTS` will have a `negative`
  but if both signs exist then the `RESULTS` will have `neutral`

I tried to use the `np.where` but failed.
My data types for the `FEATURE` is string.

Please see a sample of the data:

```
{'FEATURE': {0: '[NA] this is not a feature.',
  1: 'entertainment value[+8]',
  2: 'image quality[+6]',
  3: 'extras [-2]',
  4: 'a list cast[+2],oscar winners[+1]'},
  'SENTENCE': {0: <NA>,
  1: 'starwars trilogy',
  2: ' good for an old dvd',
  3: 'dvd no had extra features',
  4: ' good cast'}}
```

Comment: Its recommended to add a small sample from the dataframe in the question, you can do `df.head().to_dict()` and add the output to the question.

Comment: thanks for the tip have shared this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
states = {0: 'no +/-', 1: 'positive', 2: 'negative', 3: 'neutral'}
df['RESULT'] = df['FEATURE'].apply(lambda x: states.get(('+' in x) + ('-' in x) * 2))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    FEATURES    RESULT
0    AAA+AAA  positive
1    BBB-BBB  negative
2   CCC+-CCC   neutral
3   D-D+D-D+   neutral
4  E E E E E    no +/-
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df['RESULTS'] = np.where(df['FEATURES'].str.contains('+'), 'POSITIVE', 0)
df['RESULTS'] = np.where(df['FEATURES'].str.contains('-'), 'NEGATIVE', df['RESULTS'])
```

Note that if it contains both + & - it will display NEGATIVE

Comment: thanks but i get this error: error: nothing to repeat at position 0 not sure how to proceed with this...

Comment: I made a small correction above. Try it again

Answer (score 0):

First create the masking to get boolean for positive `+`, and negative `-`:

```py
>>> pMask = df['FEATURE'].str.contains('+', regex=False)
>>> nMask = df['FEATURE'].str.contains('-', regex=False)
```

Then you can use `np.select`, and assign `neutral` if both conditions are True, else assign `positive` or `negative` based on the masking, default being empty string `''`, and assign it to a new column `RESULT`:

```py
>>> df['RESULT']=np.select([(pMask)&(nMask), pMask, nMask], 
                            [['neutral'], ['positive'], 
                            ['negative']], 
                            default='')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                             FEATURE                   SENTENCE    RESULT
0        [NA] this is not a feature.                       <NA>          
1            entertainment value[+8]           starwars trilogy  positive
2                  image quality[+6]        good for an old dvd  positive
3                        extras [-2]  dvd no had extra features  negative
4  a list cast[+2],oscar winners[+1]                  good cast  positive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
                             FEATURE                   SENTENCE
0        [NA] this is not a feature.                       <NA>
1            entertainment value[+8]           starwars trilogy
2                  image quality[+6]        good for an old dvd
3                        extras [-2]  dvd no had extra features
4  a list cast[+2],oscar winners[+1]                  good cast
```

### Filter the Values based on the `str.contains`.

```
>>> pos = df['FEATURE'].str.contains('+', regex=False)
>>> neg = df['FEATURE'].str.contains('-', regex=False)
```

### Now map the values and create a new column.

```
>>> df['RESULT'] = np.where(pos, 'positive', np.where(neg, 'negative', 'neutral'))
>>> df
                             FEATURE                   SENTENCE    RESULT
0        [NA] this is not a feature.                       <NA>   neutral
1            entertainment value[+8]           starwars trilogy  positive
2                  image quality[+6]        good for an old dvd  positive
3                        extras [-2]  dvd no had extra features  negative
4  a list cast[+2],oscar winners[+1]                  good cast  positive
```